# Metamask just started throwing a -32000 error for gas estimation via web3.js

Tags: web3js, metamask

I've been using this code successfully for 8 months:

```
    const gasAmount = await this.factory.methods.createContract(
      Math.floor(new Date(contract.expirationDate).getTime() / 1000),
      contract.task,
      contract.format,
      contract.minimalLength,
      contract.minimalResolution,
      JSON.stringify(contract.location)
    ).estimateGas({
      from: this.account,
      value: web3Utils.toWei(contract.pay.toString(), 'ether')
    })
```

Last week, it started throwing this error:

> inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: stack underflow (1 <=> 8) {code:
> -32000, message: 'stack underflow (1 <=> 8)'}

Nothing I've tried has made this go away-reinstalling Metamask, commenting out the "from" and "value" fields. This is with web3.js 4.0. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the way I was passing the address into the initial construction (new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address) was wrong. The error was not thrown on the construction but on attempts to interact. To understand what was going on, I had to rewrite in ethers.js because the errors there are more informative.